# How to make a specific child element control the width of the parent?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a problem controlling the width of the second child. The first child wraps an image which has a width / height of X (dynamically calculated). The second element contains some content. The issue I have here is that if the text increases, child1 is growing too.

What do I want achieve?
I want to have the text ellipses if it exceeds the width of the first child.

Let's say we have the following example:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="child1">
        <img />
    </div>
    <p id="child2">Some random text........</p>
</div>
```

This is an example skeleton.